# Minimum number of characters needed to add in original word so that it becomes a palindrome

Tags: python, string, character, palindrome, insertion

Below is the code for above description.

Constraint 3<=N<=5000

Input is a string containing alphabets and digits only which is case sensitive.Add letters in the word at any place to make the pattern.

Issue->Code works fine on IDE but 9 out of 10 test cases are failing on Simulator(Test cases are autogenerated).Unable to comprehend the missing part due to which test cases are failing.

```
import sys

import re

def s2p(text):
    lis = list(text)  

    count = 0
    if lis[0:] == lis[::-1]:
        return count

    elif lis[0] != lis[-1]:
        lis.append(lis[0])

    for i in range(1, len(lis) - 1):

        if lis[i] == lis[-(i + 1)]:
            continue
        else:
            lis.insert(len(lis) - i, lis[i])

            count += 1  
    if lis[0:] == lis[::-1]:
        return count  

    else:
        sys.exit()

size=int(input())

try:

    assert(size in range (3,5000))

    inp = str(input())

    sample=re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', '', inp)

    #print(sample)

    if inp.isalnum()==True:

        print(s2p(sample)) 

    else:
        sys.exit()

except AssertionError:

    sys.exit()
```

Comment: If the input can contain digits, why do you remove the digits with `re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', '', inp)`?

Comment: Only letters can be added to make the word a palindrome.Digits are not considered for the same.